# How can I read a JSON array in c#

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I have this JSON array, I got it from [here](https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/).
I want to extract from it some coins price. 
Here's what I want to have:
BTC price: 15000$
XRP price: 3$
How can I achieve this in c# ?

```
[
{
    "id": "bitcoin", 
    "name": "Bitcoin", 
    "symbol": "BTC", 
    "rank": "1", 
    "price_usd": "15235.5", 
    "price_btc": "1.0", 
    "24h_volume_usd": "17910600000.0", 
    "market_cap_usd": "255647119350", 
    "available_supply": "16779700.0", 
    "total_supply": "16779700.0", 
    "max_supply": "21000000.0", 
    "percent_change_1h": "0.36", 
    "percent_change_24h": "8.91", 
    "percent_change_7d": "-3.41", 
    "last_updated": "1514994260"
}, 
{
    "id": "ripple", 
    "name": "Ripple", 
    "symbol": "XRP", 
    "rank": "2", 
    "price_usd": "2.88573", 
    "price_btc": "0.00019146", 
    "24h_volume_usd": "4799670000.0", 
    "market_cap_usd": "111790712459", 
    "available_supply": "38739144847.0", 
    "total_supply": "99993093880.0", 
    "max_supply": "100000000000", 
    "percent_change_1h": "0.88", 
    "percent_change_24h": "19.54", 
    "percent_change_7d": "120.16", 
    "last_updated": "1514994241"
}
]
```

Comment: Use newtonsoft.json to import the data into a list, then iterate over the list as you would do normally.  Which bit are you stuck with?

Comment: Please do your research, there are several questions fully answered that fills the requirement of this question.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Newtonsoft.net](http://newtonsoft.net/) for parsing of JSON data.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

You can create class to hold the data

```
Class CryptoCurrencyDetails{

 public String id {get; set;}
 public String name{get; set;}
 public String symbol{get; set;}
    .
    .
    .

public String last_updated{get; set;}
}
```

Then you can convert your JSON array into C# list by :

```
List<CryptoCurrencyDetails> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CryptoCurrencyDetails>>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use an object for mapping this Array, for example :

```
[DataContract]
public class CryptoCurrencyData
{
    [DataMember(Name ="id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //One property for each Json array member
}
```

And then use a Json serializer like this :

```
using (MemoryStream myMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonArrayString)))
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(CryptoCurrencyData));
    return (CryptoCurrencyData)serializer.ReadObject(myMemoryStream);
}
```

Comment: `DataContractJsonSerializer` pales in comparison with Newtonsoft.  Its use is not recommended.

Comment: The OP has an array, this code will only read a single item.

Comment: @Amy You are right, I didn't see the Xamarin tag...

Comment: @SunPaz that tag isn't relevant.  `DataContractJsonSerializer` performs worse and had fewer features than Newtonsoft everywhere.